# Filtering out JWT and Bearer tokens with VCR

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, vcr

I'm working with the Google Drive API via the [Google Drive Ruby gem](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) and using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to record requests.

I'm authenticating via JWT under the hood, and want to filter out both the JWT request and the bearer token which gets returned.

As I don't know either the JWT token or the Bearer token which Google gives me at runtime, I can't use `filter_sensitive_data`. As a result, I've got the following mess of code to filter after the tests run in order to sanitise my cassettes:

```
after(:each) do |example|
  # Filter out JWT and bearer tokens from requests
  if VCR.current_cassette.recording?
    interactions = VCR.current_cassette.new_recorded_interactions
    # Remove JWT token
    interactions.first.request.body.gsub! /(?<=assertion\=).*/, '<JWT_TOKEN>'
    # Get and replace access token from body
    body = JSON.parse(interactions.first.response.body)
    access_token = body['access_token']
    body['access_token'] = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
    interactions.first.response.body = body.to_json
    # Replace access token in each auth request
    interactions.drop(1).each do |i|
      i.request.headers['Authorization'][0].gsub!(access_token, '<BEARER_TOKEN>')
    end
  end
end
```

My question is a two parter really - 1) is there another way to do this?; and 2) is this even necessary at all? Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used filter_sensitive_data and came up with this:

```
VCR.configure do |config|
  config.filter_sensitive_data('<BEARER_TOKEN>') { |interaction|
    auths = interaction.request.headers['Authorization'].first
    if (match = auths.match /^Bearer\s+([^,\s]+)/ )
      match.captures.first
    end
  }
end
```

When I test, the auth header inside the cassette looks like:

```
Authorization:
- Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>
```

Notable assumptions:

- An HTTP request should only contain a single auth header
- However, that header might contain multiple comma-separated auths
- The above code only captures an auth starting with 'Bearer'
- You could tweak it for other types other than 'Bearer'